# Boundedness = covergence for a monotonically decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A monotone decreasing sequence ${x_{n}}$ converges if and only if is bounded from below

Could they please help me with this exercise?

Comment: "if and only if" means there are two things to prove.  What are they? Can you do one of them?

Comment: You want to prove that statement, right?

Comment: Anyone agrees Miguel's autogenerated gravatar is borderline inappropriate? =D

Comment: Hint: If the sequence $x_n$ converges to $L$, then $L$ is a lower bound for the sequence (why)? The other direction is a direct consequence of the Montone Convergence Theorem, proved in most introductory analysis/calculus textbooks.

Comment: Hint for the reverse implication: Let $\alpha$ be the greatest lower bound of the sequence. Show that in fact the sequence converges to $\alpha$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Why you you consider it inappropriate?

Comment: @DavidMitra Please trust me that if you don't know, then you will regret finding out.

Comment: Hint for the forward implication: contrapositive.

Comment: @David: At a guess, he thinks that it resembles a swastika. This seems to me a very considerable stretch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_n$ is bounded from below, there exist $I = \inf x_n $. Given $\epsilon > 0$. Chose $n_0$ such that 
\begin{equation}
I \le x_{n_0} < I+ \epsilon.
\end{equation}
Hence as $(x_n)$ is decreasing
\begin{equation}
n \ge n_0 \Rightarrow I \le x_n \le x_{n_0} < I + \epsilon.
\end{equation}
Then $(x_n)$ converges. Reciprocally if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, for $n > > 1$, $x_n > x -1$ and $x_n$ is bounded below.